# Check Int32 is Null

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that I can run (and I get output from it), but a few off the columns come back as null.

The code I am using in my controller is :

```
Int32 Output7 = SPOutput.GetInt32(SPOutput.GetOrdinal("ptransient"));
ViewBag.Output7 = Output7;
```

But when I run the code, I get

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'

from the "int32" line.

I have tried `Int32? Output7` etc, but I get the same error.

I've tried putting in a if Loop to check if `Output7.HasValue`, but the exception occurs prior to this.

I think I need a way of check the value BEFORE I assign it to the Int32 Output7 variable , but am stuck as to how (still a lower level noobie @ MVC).

I have googled and look thought SO (prob badly), but could not find a solution.
Could someone point out what I should be doing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `SPOutput.GetInt32()` is trying to get an `int`, not an `int?`.  Regardless of what you're assigning the result of that operation to, internally the operation *itself* is trying to produce an `int`.  And you can't produce an `int` from a `null` value.

Check if the database value is `null` before trying.  Perhaps something similar to this:

```
int? output7 = null;
if (SPOutput.GetValue(SPOutput.GetOrdinal("ptransient")) != DBNull.Value)
    output7 = SPOutput.GetInt32(SPOutput.GetOrdinal("ptransient"));
```

That way the value defaults to `null`, but is assigned to the integer value from the data *if* there is an integer value in the data.

(Note that this assumes your code is using the same data access technology that uses `DBNull.Value`, generally plain ADO.NET.)

Comment: HI, If it try this is get Hi , if I try this is get " Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'DBNull' as well

Comment: @GeraldOakham: Ah, I see why that's happening.  It's been a long time since I've used plain old ADO.NET.  I've updated the answer with another attempt, trying to get the value from the ordinal position.

Comment: THANK YOU. This worked, I changed it a bit to `                    int? Output8 = null;
                    if (SPOutput.GetValue(SPOutput.GetOrdinal("pax_group")) != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        Output8 = SPOutput.GetInt32(SPOutput.GetOrdinal("pax_group"));
                        ViewBag.Output8 = Output8;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Output8 = 0;
                    }`

Comment: You can simplify the if statement to `if(!SPOutput.IsDbNull(SPOutput.GetOrdinal("ptransient")))`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check `SPOutput` or `SPOutput.GetOrdinal("ptransient")` is null, if not, try:

```
Int32 Output7;
if (SPOutput!= System.DBNull.Value && SPOutput.GetOrdinal("ptransient")!= System.DBNull.Value)
{
  Output7 = SPOutput.GetInt32(SPOutput.GetOrdinal("ptransient"));
  ViewBag.Output7 = Output7;
}
```

Comment: ,Hi , if I try this is get " Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'DBNull'

Comment: yah I see, I think I have some stuck in my code, so you can check with this before set value for Output7:
if (SPOutput.GetValue(SPOutput.GetOrdinal("ptransient")) != DBNull.Value)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is don't use GetInt32 at all and just get the object version of the value then cast with a `as`, this will pass through int values and `DbNull` values just become normal `null`

```
Int32? Output7 = SPOutput["ptransient"] as Int32?;
ViewBag.Output7 = Output7;
```